# What parameters do I need to check in listeners for performance testing in Jmeter?

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing

I am rather new to performance testing with a basic knowledge in JMeter, I am given a task to do the performance testing for few API's. But I am not sure which parameters(connect time/latency..etc) should I be looking at in the listners to know that a particular API is performing well.

Please help me out on what paramters I need to check and which listener to use for it.

Answer (score 1):

It mainly depends on what **you**'re trying to achieve.

In case of "normal" [Load Testing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_performance_testing#Load_testing) you're supposed to have the anticipated number of users and the acceptable metrics defined in [SLAs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Service-level_agreement) or [NFRs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-functional_requirement)

So for example your system under test must serve 1000 concurrent users providing response time not more than 3 seconds. In that case you need to take a look at i.e. [Aggregate Report](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Aggregate_Report) listener and see if the average response time and/or response time [percentiles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percentile) are within the acceptable range.

The same applies to the number of errors and throughput (number of requests per second)

In case of [Stress Testing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_performance_testing#Stress_testing) I don't think Listeners will tell you the full story, if you're trying to determine application bottleneck you should rather look into charts available at [HTML Reporting Dashboard](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/generating-dashboard.html) and correlate increasing load with response time, throughput, number of errors, etc. If will give you the information regarding the [saturation point](http://hd-performance.blogspot.com/2010/05/saturation-point.html) and the first failure.

You might also want to collect some metrics from the system under test side like CPU, RAM, Network, Disk usage, database slow queries, etc. The best option is using an [APM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_performance_management) system or a [profiler tool](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_performance_analysis_tools). These metrics can also be correlated with the ones JMeter gives you.

More information: [Performance Metrics for Websites](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/207420665-Performance-Metrics-for-Websites)